# How to reverse an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, reverse

Some of you may know the method in Ruby that allows you to reverse an array:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
puts arr.reverse

#=> ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

How would one write a function (or prototype if you wish) in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at the [array page in the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) shows a [reverse method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']; arr.reverse(); console.log(arr);
[ 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun() {
    var c=["gh","jk","yu"];
    c.reverse();
    alert(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very simple way of doing it:

```
function reverse(arr){
for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
    arr.splice(i, 0, arr.shift());
}
return arr;
}
```