# Array order change

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a mongo query that returns an array in the format below, how do I change it

```
[[12, 1359410400000], [18, 1359410400000]]
```

to look like this

```
[[ 1359410400000, 12], [ 1359410400000,18]]
```

Comment: What makes this a mongodb question?

Comment: @mjhm removed the mongodb tag, added arrays tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse an array in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847171/how-to-reverse-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mongoArray.forEach(function(arr) {
    arr.reverse();
});
```

Or more concise like this:

```
mongoArray.forEach(Function.call.bind([].reverse));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newArr = [];
oldArr.forEach(function(v, i){ newArr[i] = [v[1], v[0]]; });
```

Comment: Also `newArr = oldArr.map(function (v) { return [ v[1], v[0] ]; });`

Comment: I agree with @Jonathan. If you're going to use `forEach` to make a new Array, might as well use `.map()` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: That's best way IMO, I'd post as answer.